# Server is unavailable error in wso2 emm mobile agent

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am trying to login to the wso2 emm mobile agent but an error of "Server is unavailable .Please contact admin " is coming.How to resolve this?

Comment: First of all need to make sure server and device(both) are in same network.and Enter the server IP and the port as your server address.If you have not configured WSO2 EMM for HTTPS communication use the  http port       ex: HTTP: 10.10.10.123:9763

Comment: Yes my device is not connected over the same network, let me connect over the same network and check.Thanks for the useful advice.